# Как автоматически заполнить логин и пароль на другом сайте?

Tags: php, get

Как мне вставить логин и пароль в данные поля и отправить по кнопке

Логин

```
<input name="emailOrUsername" id="emailOrUsername" type="text" class="rc-input__element error" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Адрес email или логин" autofocus="" control-id="ControlID-1">
```

Пароль

```
<input name="pass" id="pass" type="password" class="rc-input__element error" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Пароль" autofocus="" control-id="ControlID-2">
```

Кнопка

```
<button class="rc-button rc-button--primary login" control-id="ControlID-3">Авторизация</button>
```

[image: Пример окна авторизации]

У меня был код для другого сайта, но на этом не работает

```
<form method="post" action="http://">
<h1>Login</h1><input class="class" type="text" value="Логин" maxlength="20" name="login"></br>
<h1>Pass</h1>
<input class="class" type="password" maxlength="20" name="pass"></br>
<input type="image" value="Войти">
</form>
```

Comment: видимо отправить post-запрос с помощью php?